# Need further understanding in the next unless code I'm reading

Tags: perl

I need help with 2 things on this code that I'm reading. First, is I keep seeing this inside of while loop to read a file:

```
wile(<filename>){
 next unless (/\w/);
 chomp;
 s/^\s*//;
 s/^\s*$//;
 my($name, $datatype, $io, $dummy) = split /\s*,\s*/, $_, 4;
}
```

So, I'm wondering what that is doing? Because there are commas in the same line being read, so wouldn't the commas make it go to the next iteration? SO how would it split the lines if it is going to another iteration when the commas are being read?

Another one I'm stomped by is:

```
while (<AP>) {
   chomp;
   s/
//g;
}
```

I have no idea what that code is actually substituting...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first snippet:

1. Reads a line from a filehandle called `filename`.  This is a really bad name for a filehandle
2. It skips the processing if there is not even a single `\w` (*word character*) on the line.
   The `next unless (/\w/);` is the same as `next if not (/\w/)`. Note that there is no need for parenthesis -- `next unless /\w/;` is fine.
   A *word character* is, from [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html)

   > `\w` matches a word character (alphanumeric or `_`), not just `[0-9a-zA-Z_]` but also digits and characters from non-roman scripts
3. It removes (only) the newline with `chomp`. Then it removes leading spaces, if any
4. It removes blank lines, the ones with only spaces on them
5. It splits the line by commas, allowing that they have spaces before and/or after. It also limits the number of terms returned, to `4`. This means that it returns the first three comma-separated fields, and then all the rest as one string in the last element of the list

The second snippet is really bad, whatever it is meant to do. (Remove spaces on the line?)

---

Comments

It is far better to use *lexical filehandles*, rather than barenames.  So you'd open a file as

```
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
```

and read it by `while (my $line = <$fh>)` or by `while (<$fh>)`.

---

Normally you'll see lines skipped if they have nothing other than spaces

```
next unless /\S/;  # or
next if /^\s*$/;
```

Using `\w` also skips lines with some characters (other than what is matched by `\w`), which means that one had better be very sure that those are fine to skip.

Here it may be meant to skip a line with commas but no `\w` (comma is not matched by `\w`), for which [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) would return spaces (or empty strings) in a list. I find this a bit hidden and fragile.  I'd drop lines with spaces only, and handle possible loose commas in processing. As it stands it doesn't help with `,,a,` anyway, what yields `('', '', 'a')`. So checking is probably needed in any case.

Note that altogether this code leaves trailing spaces. When `split` is invoked with the optional fourth argument it keeps all spaces, and they haven't been removed otherwise.

Comment: for the first snippet all I had a question abut was the next unless part... your answer helps me a lot. I thought it would read the next line as soon as a non alphanumeric character was read.  The second one, I also agree its a terrible code, there are spaces and new lines in the file but chomp would take care of new lines, and I see them substituting spaces with s/\s*//g everywhere else that's why this is stomping me.

Comment: `unless (condition)` === `if (!condition)`

Comment: @raina77ow so that's what those two lines are doing? because they use `s/\s*$//` everywhere else in this script.

Comment: @sikquiver  I updated the answer.  Let me know if there is more to add/edit. I didn't know what exactly you had in mind, thanks for clarifying it.  However, the rest of the code just demands comments as well.

Comment: @sikquiver Agreed -- that second snippet should not be there.  I cannot tell what it is meant to do either.  As for stripping spaces, this is a common way of doing it, and it is generally a bit faster than combining them in one line (what you can also see around).

Comment: @zdim your 4th comment is a little off, `s/^\s*$//` removes blank lines from the document. that's why the `^` is in the code. But i guess chomp would also do that?

Comment: @sikquiver Correct, thank you, updated.  So the code removes leading spaces and empty lines. Leaving possible trailing spaces.  That's a bit strange.

Comment: @zdim I think the split is taking care of any trailing spaces on the data I'm going through, that's why it's not there... thanks for the help!

Comment: @sikquiver I updated the answer, with an explanation of why they use skip lines with `\w` (and not spaces only) -- answering your question about commas (which I forgot about initially).  Thank you for the attribution.  As for trailing spaces -- `split` _keeps them with that fourth argument_.  If you say `split '  ', $var` it indeed drops them, but with `split ' ', $var, 3` it keeps everything.

Comment: The second snippet is supposed to remove newlines in the string. It would be better written as: `s/\n//g;`

Comment: @shawnhcorey  That crossed my mind, too, unlikely as it seemed -- but it didn't work in my test. (I wasn't very careful though.)

Comment: @zdim That's because the second snippet is unreliable.